# Add numbers 0 - 59 to a NSMutableArray to display in a pickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, uipickerview

I have a `UIPickerView`. What I want to do is display numbers 0 - 59. I tried the following code:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 60;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSMutableArray *timing = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        [timing addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }
    return timing[row];
}
```

But I got this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000002'
```

I don't know what it means.

When I try adding a string to `timing` (instead of `[NSNumber...]`) it then works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

This method is supposed to return an `NSString`, but you’re returning an object from the `timing` array, which you just filled with `NSNumber` objects. `__NSCFNumber` is a private subclass of `NSNumber`. Something inside the picker view is assuming that the object that you returned is an `NSString`, and is asking for its `length`.

The solution is to return an `NSString`. The simplest way would be something like:

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", timing[row]];
```

---

### Bonus

Your code is algorithmically slow, because it has to run a loop to create the `timing` array every time that method is called. If your code is actually supposed to do what it does in your sample (i.e. if you didn’t simplify it for the question), then you could do this:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    // @(row) is equivalent to [NSNumber numberWithInteger:row]
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @(row)];
}
```

### Extra Bonus

Since your numbers are going to be user-facing, you should use `NSNumberFormatter` ([link to tutorial](http://ios.eezytutorials.com/nsnumberformatter-by-example.php#.VOqZFUJ8vzI)) to make sure they are formatter correctly for the user’s locale.

Comment: I didn't understand the Extra Bonus part. Also, I tried doing the "Bonus" code and it worked. But in xcode it gives me a warning "Implicit conversion losses integer..."

Comment: Here’s a tutorial on `NSNumberFormatter`: http://ios.eezytutorials.com/nsnumberformatter-by-example.php#.VOqZFUJ8vzI

Comment: Where is the warning? There should be a little triangle that points to the part of the code where the warning is.

Comment: at the return statement

Comment: When I paste my code into Xcode, I don't get that warning. Are you sure you used the right string format specifier? In my examples, it's `%@`, not `%d`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to return NSString from your `-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component`
method. Right now you are returning NSNumber. And the compiler does not warn you because an NSArray can contain any object and it just does not know that this one is array of NSNumbers instead of NSStrings.

You probably wanted to add NSStrings with numbers to `timing` like `[timing addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];`

Also it looks like you don't need `timing` array at all — right now you are creating it for every row and use just a single element from it. You can return string with number `row` directly like so

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row];
}
```

Comment: `%d` is going to be grumpy, depending on the architecture. Rather than deal with messy casting, you can just use `%@` and wrap `row` in an `NSNumber` using `@(row)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is supposed to return a `NSString *`, but you return a `NSNumber  *`

You should write it this way:

```
 - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row];
}
```

No need to build an array every time you get called.